# Makefile with space in library directory

Tags: makefile, space

When a library path contains spaces, it cannot find the path.
So I use quotation marks to wrap the path. The path is found, but it can't find the library in the directory.

eg:
`Debug_Library_Path=-L"../Externals/TextLibrary/libs/with space/gccDebug/"`
`Release_Library_Path=-L"../Externals/TextLibrary/libs/with space/gccRelease/"`

`Debug_Libraries=-Wl,--start-group -lTextLibrary  -Wl,--end-group`
`Release_Libraries=-Wl,--start-group -lTextLibrary  -Wl,--end-group`

It prompts that:  can not find "-lTextLibrary"

Does anyone know what may be causing this problem?

Comment: Could you please provide information about the actual command that generates the error?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message states that `-lTextLibrary`can not be found (not TextLibrary!), I doubt that this is a matter of the path. Rather, your program interprets your option as input file. Check what kind of arguments your program consumes and maybe try to change the order of arguments/options.